# In Github actions work flow continuous integration how to build asp.net 4.5 in Github on code push?

Tags: asp.net, github, build, workflow, github-actions

I have created a build workflow on github Actions tab which will build the project on code push. I have created build.yml file something like this

````
name: CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    name: Build

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: Run dotnet MyProjectName
    - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        echo Add other actions to build,
        echo test, and deploy your project.```


But its .net framework 4.5 project so this command is for .net core. 
Is there any other command for building the application on Github server.
````

Comment: you will need .net framework installed, msbuild.exe installed

Answer (score 2):

Windows-latest has all the build tools installed already. You can directly use msbuild instead of dotnet core. Here is the reference to all the tools installed on the windows-latest and other OS that are supported

https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners#windows-server-2019